# generate a random int from a range which is not currently shown in a row

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm doing sudoku in python, I want to randomly fill up a row which has blanks.

so I have a function that detects the blank positions and also a function that generates ints to fill.

Say, if a row is `[1 , 2 , ?, ?]`
When the position function hit the first `'?'`, the random function should provide a choice of 3 or 4. Then is 3 has been filled in, the the position funtion hits the second `'?'`, the random function should only provides a choice of `'4'`.

The problem is my results are wrong: for instance, where `-1` indicates blanks:

```
[[-1 -1  3  4]
 [ 3 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 2  3 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1]]

[[1 4 3 4]
 [3 4 1 1]
 [2 3 4 3]
 [3 1 4 2]]
```

The part codes are:

```
self.F1 = np.where(self.oriMatrix == -1)

def randgit(self, row):
    while True:
        digit = randint(1, self.shape)
        for col in range(0, self.shape):
            if digit == self.pMatrix[row,col]:
                break
        return digit

def randFill(self):
    for mark in range(0, self.F1[0].size):
        pos = [self.F1[0][mark], self.F1[1][mark]]
        self.pMatrix[pos[0], pos[1]] = self.randgit(pos[0])
```

`pMatrix` is this the 4x4 matrix, can someone figure out my bugs or has a better way to do it?

Comment: Wild guess: replace `break` with `continue`.

Comment: Other than `import numpy as np` and `from random import *`, and that this is in some class, what else am I missing?  Can you show the complete definition?

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say exactly what your question is with your description and incomplete code.

Here's what I'm guessing you're asking:

> We're given a row *r* that has *n* elements in it.
>
> For each element in *r* equal to -1, fill it with a value *x*, that is:
>
> 1. In the range of 1 <= *x* <= *n*, and
> 2. Not already used in the row

If that's a proper restatement of your question, consider something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import random

m = np.array([
    [-1, -1,  3,  4],
    [ 3, -1, -1, -1],
    [ 2,  3, -1, -1],
    [-1, -1, -1, -1]])

for (i,r) in enumerate(m):
    all_values = set([(x+1) for x in range(len(r))])    # All possible values in [1,n]
    tak_values = set(r)                                 # "Taken" values already in r
    tak_values.discard(-1)                              # Discard -1 from the set
    rem_values = all_values - tak_values                # "Remaining" values, from
    print("Row %d" % i)                                 #   which to choose x
    print("  Remaining  values: %s" % rem_values)
    print("  Random choice: %d" % random.choice(list(rem_values)))
```

Which, for me, just printed:

```
Row 0
  Remaining  values: set([1, 2])
  Random choice: 1
Row 1
  Remaining  values: set([1, 2, 4])
  Random choice: 2
Row 2
  Remaining  values: set([1, 4])
  Random choice: 4
Row 3
  Remaining  values: set([1, 2, 3, 4])
  Random choice: 1
```

I tried to "go slow" in the above code, so you could easily inspect what the different variables are, etc.  Of course, with a lot of these answers, we could likely shorten it significantly.

Comment: Thanks! My thought is in the question we have a puzzle, some blanks are missing. we have a same choice set for each row, however based on the answer I think we need find examine the row and kick out the existing numbers from the choice set and the random fill in the number from the set. For, this "for (i,r) in enumerate(m)", I'm not understanding it, would you mind to explain a little bit what dose it do?

Comment: [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) (docs linked) is a built-in function that "wraps" an iterable `sequence`, such that, when you iterate over the output of enumerate, you get 2 element tuples, the first element is the index (0,1,2,...) and the second element is the corresponding element in `sequence`.  For example, `for (i,v) in [2,4,6,8]` would yield the tuples `(0,2)`, `(1,4)`, `(2,6)`, `(3,8)`.